# Make a slash command private

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to make this slash command private. Where do I insert the `defaultPermissions: false` line?

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Checks that the bot is online.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#9ea687')
            .setTitle('Pong!')
            .setDescription(`Latency is ${Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp}ms.`)
            .setThumbnail('url')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({text: 'text'});
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.setDefaultPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/SlashCommandBuilder?scrollTo=setDefaultPermission) method, like this:

```js
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('ping')
  .setDescription('Checks that the bot is online.')
  .setDefaultPermission(false)
```

Comment: Ah ok thank you! Btw, do you know how you get the id of a slash command? The documentation seems to want a number.

Comment: You're welcome! It really depends on where you want to get it. You can get it from an `interaction` (it's `interaction.commandId`), or you can fetch all commands (using `guild.commands.fetch()`) and check their `id`s.